# From arm_navigation_msgs::RobotTrajectory to pr2_controllers_msgs::JointTrajectoryGoal

Tags: ompl, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I'm looking for a solution for this problem in Internet, but I'don't found anything.
I'm working with OMPL planning, and when I find a plan, I'd like to execute in the PR2 Controller.

Anybody know how I can do it??
From: arm_navigation_msgs/RobotTrajectory trajectory
to: pr2_controllers_msgs::JointTrajectoryGoal

Redards.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49120/from-arm_navigation_msgs::robottrajectory--to-pr2_controllers_msgs::jointtrajectorygoal/) by [Sanxano](https://answers.ros.org/users/1103/sanxano/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2012-11-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
arm_navigation_msgs::GetMotionPlan::Response response;
pr2_controllers_msgs::JointTrajectoryGoal goal;

goal.trajectory = response.trajectory.joint_trajectory;
```

---

Originally posted by [Sanxano](https://answers.ros.org/users/1103/sanxano/) with karma: 70 on 2012-11-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0